# Print all 4 pings in a string line separated by comma's

Tags: c#, csv, ping

My code is working fine, but where it is saving the results to the .csv file I need a make a few changes there. 
My results are:

```
www.yahoo.com , 98.139.183.24 , 137
www.att.com , 23.72.249.145 , 20
www.yahoo.com , 98.139.183.24 , 120
www.att.com , 23.72.249.145 , 16
```

and I would like my result to be:

```
www.yahoo.com , 137 , 120
www.att.com , 20 , 16
```

In this example I shared only two results, I'm actually returning 4 results and I need to put them all in a single line and I also need to get rid of the IP address. Please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> lstWebSites = new List<string>();
            lstWebSites.Add("www.yahoo.com");
            lstWebSites.Add("www.att.com");
            lstWebSites.Add("www.verizon.com");
            string filename = @"PingLog.csv";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true)) 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    foreach(string website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        //writer.WriteLine(website, lstWebSites);
                        try
                        {
                            Ping myPing = new Ping();
                            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);
                            if (reply != null)
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine(website + " , " + reply.Address.ToString() + " , " + reply.RoundtripTime);
                            }
                        }                   
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use a dictionary<string, List<int>>()

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show all the results of your Ping calls then, instead of a simply `List<string>` to keep the names of the sites, you could use a `Dictionary<string, List<PingReply>>`. In this way, for each ping toward a certain site you keep a list of all the `PingReply` received and at the end of the loop you write everything inside a file (with a little help of Linq)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Dictionary to keep the sites list and the list of replies for each site
    Dictionary<string, List<PingReply>> lstWebSites = new Dictionary<string, List<PingReply>>();
    lstWebSites.Add("www.yahoo.com", new List<PingReply>());
    lstWebSites.Add("www.att.com", new List<PingReply>());
    lstWebSites.Add("www.verizon.com", new List<PingReply>());
    string filename = @"d:\temp\PingLog.csv";

    // Start your loops
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        foreach (string website in lstWebSites.Keys)
        {
            try
            {
                Ping myPing = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);
                if (reply != null)
                {
                    // Do not write to file here, just add the 
                    // the reply to your dictionary using the site key
                    lstWebSites[website].Add(reply);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
            }
        }


    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
    {
        // For each site, extract the RoundtripTime and 
        // use string.Join to create a comma separated line to write
        foreach(string website in lstWebSites.Keys)
            writer.WriteLine(website + " , " + 
                string.Join(",", lstWebSites[website]
                      .Select(x => x.RoundtripTime)
                      .ToArray()));
    }

    string fileText = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    Console.WriteLine(fileText);

}
```

Comment: wow, I just got done making all of the changes and its exactly how I wanted it. Thank you so much. This was a really big help and its perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to move for loop inside the foreach loop and collect ping results for every site. You can change your code to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.yahoo.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com"
            };

            var filename = @"PingLog.csv";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {
                    foreach (var website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        var roundTripTimes = new List<long>();

                        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var myPing = new Ping();
                                var reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);

                                if (reply != null)
                                {
                                    roundTripTimes.Add(reply.RoundtripTime);
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
                            }
                        }

                        writer.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", website, string.Join(" , ", roundTripTimes));
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But it's better to learn some LINQ (e.g. [LINQ 101](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php)) and write code in a less verbose manner like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.yahoo.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com"
            };

            var filename = @"PingLog.csv";

            var pings = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).SelectMany(_ => lstWebSites.Select(ws => new {Ping = new Ping(), WebSite = ws}));
            var result = pings.Select(_ => new {Reply = _.Ping.Send(_.WebSite, 1000), _.WebSite}).ToLookup(_ => _.WebSite, p => p.Reply.RoundtripTime);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
            {
                foreach (var res in result)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", res.Key, string.Join(" , ", res));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This sample lacks exception handling but you can understand the main idea.

Comment: I'm getting a red line under RoundtripTime where I have if (result != null) roundTripTimes.Add(result.RoundtripTime);

Comment: What message do you see in a tooltip when you point mouse on this line?

Comment: 'System.Linq.ILookup<string,long>'does not contain a definition for 'Roundtrip' and no extension method 'Roundtrip' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.ILookup<string,long>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or sn assembly reference?)

Comment: These 2 pieces of code are 2 different solutions for your task. Seems that you're trying to use result variable from the second example in the first solution.

Comment: yea I put these in place of the Ping myPing and PingReply reply....I thought thats what you meant...so what am I suppose to do?

Comment: Ok I got it, I understand....sorry for the confusion, this is great. Thank you :)